# PHP Regex all characters except numbers and boolean

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP and I have developed a script to sanitize a JSON string.

One step in the process is to prevent numbers and booleans from being double-quoted explicitly.

Below is my regex pattern to exclude numbers.

```
/\:[\s\n\t]*([^0-9\{\}\[\],\"]+)[\s\n\t]*/i
```

However, I'm trying to enhance it so that it includes boolean as well i.e. true and false. Without this, any booleans will be double-quoted (which I want to avoid).

Any ideas how I can improve the regex above?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you're using this for? As php's `json_encode` won't wrap a true boolean value with quotes. (See: `echo json_encode(true);`)

Comment: Won't not that it will be easier once you have the variables in array format (after json_decode)?

Comment: @Yoshi: It's just a general purpose script to clean up JSON that is not well-formed before it is passed to json_decode. Sometimes JSON from APIs and other sources might have a few 'screws loose' as they say, so this just deals with that.

Comment: @ajreal: json_decode only works when your JSON is well-formed.

Comment: I'd also like to add that this regex is for one of eleven preg_replace operations on the JSON string. I just needed help on this specific part. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `?!` assertion to exclude booleans from being matched by your character class blacklist.

```
 /\:[\s\n\t]*(?!true|false)([^0-9\{\}\[\],\"]+)[\s\n\t]*/i
```

Btw, the character class as it is will fail for floats. Also I'm not entirely convinced of your "sanitization" approach. It seems you only postprocess some bare array attributes here. (And it'll furthermore fail if they are composed of more than one word that isn't enclosed in dquotes.)

Comment: Thanks mario, I'll try this out now. Regarding your comment on the "sanitization" approach, this single pattern is one part of an eleven part process. I'm using eleven other regex patterns to do various things to the JSON file before it's actually sanitized. I'll also look into the float issue now as well. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok. This works perfectly. Thanks a lot. And floats work ok as well. Cheers.